# Can you help me solve for $f(x)$ in this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

$$\frac{f(x)}{n-f(x)}=\frac{(n-f(x))^a}{e^a}$$
for a small whole number $a$, I've tried to differentiate both sides, but it gets me no where.

Comment: I made an edit -- is this what you mean?

Comment: It is easy to go to $e^af(x)=(n-f(x))^{a+1}$.  If $a$ is a small whole number this is a polynomial in $f(x)$ which you might solve with the appropriate formula.  Otherwise, I don't think you will solve it.

Comment: Yes. I appreciate your help. Can you help me with the equation?

Comment: Interesting. No body commented "what you have tried"

Comment: for a small whole number a, I've tried to differentiate both sides, but it gets me no where.

Comment: Are $n$ and $a$ integers?

Comment: There is no need to name the unknown $f(x)$. Why don't you use $x$ ?

Comment: What do you call *small* ?

Comment: If $a$ is small enough, you can expand the formula that @RossMillikan gave you and truncate it at some point to obtain an approximate solution.

Comment: But are $a$ and $n$ *integers*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, lets simplify the expression:

$$\frac{f(x)}{n-f(x)}=\frac{(n-f(x))^a}{e^a}\implies e^af(x)=(n-f(x))^{a+1}$$

Notice that $x$ does not occur except as a variable in $f(x)$, so there is no way to reduce this to  $f(x)=\langle\text{expression containing $x$}\rangle$. In other words, $f(x)$ is just "some unknown."

We can replace $f(x)$ with $x$, and try to obtain the solution set [in $x$] for the expression:

$$(n-x)^{a+1}-e^a x=0$$

*Assuming* $a$ is an *positive integer*, this is a polynomial that can be expanded using the binomial theorem:

$$e^ax-\sum_{k=0}^{a+1}\left(\begin{matrix}a+1\\k\end{matrix}\right)(-x)^kn^{a+1-k}=0$$

As per the Abel-Ruffini theorem, there is no general solution for polynomials with of degree $\ge5$ with arbitrary coefficients. A solution formula *may* exist in terms of $a$ and $n$ for polynomials of *this specific*, but I wouldn't know how to prove this. You might try asking an expert in algebraic number theory. Otherwise, your best bet is to solve the equation on a case-by-case basis.